# How to get the product collection based on catalog & cart price rules?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, product-list, product-collection, catalog-rules

I am trying to get all products based on catalog price rules and cart price rules under all categories which is valid for today's date in Magento 2

Answer (score 7):

For catalog rule, if you look at 
`vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Rule`

You will find method `getMatchingProductIds()` which return an array of all matching products for a particular rule.

So load the `rule Model` by using `rule id` by object manager or constructor injection and call `getMatchingProductIds()` method. Hope it works.