# Magento 2. Get discount end date from product model

Tags: magento2, product, php, discount, catalog-price-rules

I have a module, that output's products with discounts (discounts provided by catalog price rules).

How get each product (`\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`) discount end date? What should I inject into constructor?

Comment: Please refer to http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108116/how-to-get-the-product-collection-based-on-catalog-cart-price-rules or http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-get-list-products-from-catalog-rule-condition/

Comment: @AnkitShah thank you for the answer. I found that way, but thought there could be a better one to get discount rule end date right from the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the same approach, that was suggested in the comment.

[How to get the product collection based on catalog & cart price rules?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108116/how-to-get-the-product-collection-based-on-catalog-cart-price-rules)

Here is code of my block.

```
protected $rules;

protected $dateHelper;

//...

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule $rules,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $dateHelper,
//...
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->rules                    = $rules;
        $this->dateHelper               = $dateHelper;
//...

        return parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    /**
     * Get passed product discount end date at the passed format
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Zend_Db_Statement_Exception
     */
    public function getProductDiscountEndDate($product, $format = 'd F')
    {
        foreach ($this->rules->getResourceCollection() as $rule) {
            /**
             * @var \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule $rule
             */
            if ($rule->getMatchingProductIds()[$product->getId()][1]) {
                {
                    return $this->dateHelper->date($format, $rule->getToDate());
                }
            }
        }

        return '';
    }
```